# How do I make Git Shell open Bash instead of PowerShell?

Tags: bash, git, powershell, github

I have GitHub for Windows installed. In the options, I have selected Git Bash instead of PowerShell, and when I click on "Open in Git Shell" from within GitHub for Windows, it correctly opens Git Bash. However, if I click on Git Shell on the start menu, it opens PowerShell. How do I fix this?

This used to work. I believe it stopped working when I upgraded from a beta of Windows 10 to the RTM.

Comment: Can you simply edit the shortcut?

Comment: The shortcut links to github with --open-shell, it doesn't point direct to bash.

Comment: As a kind of solution: don't use Git Bash, use Cygwin with git installed. It's not an advise, it's how I do and it works.

Answer (score 1):

To change the shell that you use do the following:

1. Click on the cog in the upper right of the GitHub gui
2. Select `Options`
3. Directly under `Clone Path` there is an option: `Default Shell`
4. Select the shell you want to use when you go to start>git shell
5. Click Save

Now when you select Git Shell from your start menu it will open Git Bash.